# iphone facebook wall posting with image map link

Tags: iphone, facebook, mapkit, fbconnect

is possible to attach a link (image) of a google map on the side of my wallpost throug iphone?
my wall post is ok, but i've no idea how to do with the map.
Ps in my app i've implemented also mapkit, i don't know if i make a gquery with coordinate to obtain map link or i must work using the position that i have on mapkit

i've found my solution with google static maps :D

here's my code:

```
    dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"{ \"name\":\"%@ si trova a %@\"," "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\"," 
                     "\"src\":\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=100x100&zoom=14&markers=color:blue|label:here|%g,%g&mobile=true&sensor=false\","
                     "\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],}",
                     _facebookName, citta.text, mylat, mylong ];
```

Answer (score 1):

to post a image use the following code (extracted from demo app

```
- (IBAction) publishStream: (id)sender {

  SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

  NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                               @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

  NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"a long run", @"name",
                            @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                            @"it is fun", @"description",
                            @"http://itsti.me/", @"href",
                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"image", @"type",
                              @"http://www.gogle.com/", @"href",
                              @"http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/457512510/iconoTwitter_bigger.gif", @"src",nil]
                             , nil ]
                            ,@"media", nil];


  NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
  NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 kAppId, @"api_key",
                                 @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                 attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                 nil];


  [_facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
          andParams: params
        andDelegate:self];

}
```